# How to construct object oriented programming in pseudo code?

Tags: data-structures, programming-languages

I am studying a data structures course in which we have given many assignments on constructing data structures (like trees, arrays, and linked lists).

In class template, what kind of notation should I write for these operators (::,->) and the others operators which are used in C++? Can anyone elaborate more about writing pseudo-code for object oriented programs?

Comment: There is no standard for pseudocode. Use anything you want, as long as its meaning is clear.

Comment: If there's some reason you care about C++, why not just use C++? That way you can actually test your code and there's no ambiguity. Even if you don't write a full program, I see no reason to use pseudo-code. If you aren't tied to C++, then I recommend using a language with a more concise syntax e.g. Python. I personally think pseudo-code is a bad idea in general, though certainly there are situations, like at a blackboard, where abbreviating real code makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudocode has no formal definition. Use whatever notation you want, as long as it is either self-explanatory (even for people unaware of C++) or explained in the text.

I suggest looking at several textbooks and papers to see what the "industry standard" is, and using something similar.

Comment: you probably right, i should go through some text books. but i found a website  where almost every thing converted into pseudo-code from c++ program. i know that there is no standard for pseudo-code. but i asked this question to know about standard pseudo-code for Object Oriented Programming (like you said industrial type of standard)